# Icecast2 and multicast

Tags: multicast

Does anyone know if Icecast2 supports multicast?

I've been searching for a while and I found nothing on neither docs or FAQ

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application multicast, yes... But *not* multicast in the IPv4 sense. What is the use-case? What are you planning to do?